# How to add optional values to an array in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having issues with appending an optional value to an array in Swift. The view I'm writing is for the creation of a routine for the gym. However my Routine object is not being instantiated as it should be.

I have experience with other programming languages but I am fairly new to Swift, and optionals.

My ViewController contains an optional variable:

```
var routine: Routine?
```

Where the Routine class contains:

```
name: String
exerciseList: [String]()
numOfSets: [Int]()
```

When I am preparing it to send the newly created routine to my other ViewController, I take the values from user input to edit the fields of the object.

```
let name = routineName.text ?? ""
let numberOne = Int(numOfSetsOne.text ?? "0") //numOfSetsOne is a text label
routine?.exerciseList.append(selectedExerciseOne!) //Haven't tested to see if this works yet
routine?.numOfSets[0] = numberOne! //This line is not working 
routine = Routine(name: name)
```

To try a little debugging I put print statements on either side of the line like so:

```
print ("numberOne Value: \(numberOne!)")
routine?.numOfSets[0] = numberOne!
print ("numOfSets[0] Value: \(routine?.numOfSets[0])")
```

I expected the output from the second print statement to be identical to the first. However the terminal output:

```
numberOne Value: 3
numOfSets[0] Value: nil
```

Does anyone know what has gone wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: `var routine: Routine?` is initially `nil`. You probably want to assign `routine = Routine(name: name)` *before* calling the methods.

Comment: @MartinR This was spot on. Thank you

Comment: A routine is better modelled by a struct. Routines don't have identity. If you have two routines named "5x5 deadlifts", with a exercise "deadlift", and sets: `[5, 5, 5, 5, 5]`, then they're identical. I would switch Routine over to a struct, then I would take advantage of the member wise initializer to do a one-shot intitialization, in which the initializer takes `name`, `exerciseList`, and `numOfSets` as params, and sets them all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared a property that *may* contain a `Routine`, but you have not assigned an instance of `Routine` to that property before trying to use it.

This means that, for example,

```
routine?.numSets[0] = numberOne!
```

doesn't do anything - `routine` is `nil` and so the statement is skipped.

You should create an appropriate `init` function for your `Routine` class and use that to create a new `Routine` and assign it to `routine`

For example:

```
class Routine {
    var name: String
    var exerciseList = [String]()
    var numberOfSets = [Int]()

    init(named: String) {
        self.name = named
    }
}
```

Then you can say

```
let name = routineName.text ?? ""
let numberOne = Int(numOfSetsOne.text ?? "0") 
self.routine = Routine(named: name)
self.routine?.numberOfSets.append(numberOne!)
```

Coordinating related arrays can get a bit messy, so I would use a single array:

```
struct ExerciseSet {
    let exerciseName: String
    let sets: Int
}


class Routine {
    var name: String
    var exerciseList = [ExerciseSet]()

    init(named: String) {
        self.name = named
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Routine` is not initialised before its being assigned value

try

```
let name = routineName.text ?? ""
let numberOne = Int(numOfSetsOne.text ?? "0") 

routine = Routine(name: name)

routine?.exerciseList.append(selectedExerciseOne!) 
routine?.numOfSets[0] = numberOne!
```